# Unix time conversions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to get the GMT in unix time. I use the following code:

```
        public static long GetGMTInMS()
        {
            var unixTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() -
                new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

            return (long)unixTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
```

To then convert the unix time back to a DatTime object, I use this:

```
        public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
        {
            System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
            return dtDateTime;
        }
```

When I run it, the `GetGMTInMS()` `1320249196267`. When I pass it to `UnixTimeStampToDateTime()` I get `{11/2/2011 11:53:16 AM}`

Which is fine. That is the correct time fro when I ran my code. The issue I have is when I try and put `1320249196267` into an unix time converter, such as [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm), it returns the totally wrong time.

The other issue, is i am in the eastern time zone. This returned the time in my time zone. Is this something that the `DateTime` object handles or am I not getting the GMT.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Converting-Unix-Timestamps-to-DateTime-and-Vice-Versa-in-C-

Answer (score 134, accepted):

"Unix timestamp" means *seconds* since the epoch in most situations rather than milliseconds... be careful! However, things like Java use "milliseconds since the epoch" which may be what you *actually* care about - despite the tool you showed. It really depends on what you need.

Additionally, you shouldn't be doing anything with local time. Stick to universal time throughout.

I would have:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch =
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static long GetCurrentUnixTimestampMillis()
{
    return (long) (DateTime.UtcNow - UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
}

public static DateTime DateTimeFromUnixTimestampMillis(long millis)
{
    return UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(millis);
}

public static long GetCurrentUnixTimestampSeconds()
{
    return (long) (DateTime.UtcNow - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
}

public static DateTime DateTimeFromUnixTimestampSeconds(long seconds)
{
    return UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(seconds);
}
```

Comment: Should the returned type be `ulong` instead of long, as UNIX timestamps cannot be negative?

Comment: @ErikSchierboom: Well that depends - there are plenty of scenarios where "seconds since the Unix epoch" or "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" are used where they *can* be negative. Given that `long.MaxValue` seconds is ever such a long way away, I think it makes more sense to be flexible and accept negative values for times before 1970.

Comment: Recently you can now use  DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()

Answer (score 5):

UNIX time is seconds since 1/1/1970, not milliseconds.  Change the code to use seconds rather than milliseconds and it should work,

Comment: I see no reason for the use of local time *anywhere* in the OP's code. .. I don't *think* it breaks anything in this case, but it makes the code harder to verify.