# Odd Unix Timestamp conversion

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

i am working with windows phone 8 and need to convert a DateTime Object into a unix timestamp.

I know there are lots of posts on how to do that, but I have an odd mistake i just cant figure out.

I am doing this:

```
double val = (value.Ticks - New DateTime(1970,1,1).Ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
```

where value is the DateTime Object i want to convert to a unix timestamp.
I know that value contains the right Time, 
(during debugging i can see it has the right date+time)

but the converted unix value is always +2 hours off.
There has to be an issue with time zones.

Can someone help me?  I find dealing with timezones very very annoying under WP, because there are no methods to convert to a specific time zone other than UTC or Local.

Comment: I've added the c# tag, since I presume that's the language you're using. If not, please replace the tag by one for the language you're actually using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix time conversions in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983441/unix-time-conversions-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Don't do it like that.  [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7983514/634824) to this question has all you need.  But you need to understand that not all `DateTime`s are created equal.  The `.Kind` matters - which probably explains the discrepancy you mentioned.

Comment: Yes i found Jon Skeet's answer, and i tried his solution. Let's say its 12:00 in my country, then UTC time is 10:00 and the result of (DateTime.UtcNow - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds  (where UnixEpoch is utc)  would be 12:00, which is the right time for me, but i cant see why, because DateTime.UtcNow is off 2 hours. The problem here is that i need it to work in different timezones as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), the 3-argument constructor for `DateTime`:

```
DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)
```

"Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to the specified year, month, and day." It doesn't have a way to specify the time zone, and the documentation doesn't specify the time zone of the result. I'd guess that it's local time.

There's another constructor:

```
DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, DateTimeKind)
```

that "Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to the specified year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) or local time".

Try replacing

```
New DateTime(1970,1,1).Ticks
```

by

```
New DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks
```

to get a DateTime representing 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC** (if I'm remembering the syntax correctly).

Comment: thanks, but I already tried that. No matter what i do, the time is always wrong. Now i installed the Noda-Time library, there i can at least get the right time zone, but i haven't figured out how to get the current time in this time zone.

Comment: If you tried it and it didn't work, why did you accept this answer?

Comment: I learned that it did indeed work. I thought the unix timestamp depends on the local time, but i learned that the unix timestamp should be the same at every location and that it is not an issue that it does not represent my local time zone