# How to sort date in an array which has range in iphone

Tags: sorting

I've an array of dates as follows:18-22 Agust 2014,
21-23 September 2014,
14-18 September 2014,
27-29 June 2014,
13-14 July 2014,
3-4 August 2014,
17-21 August 2014,
14-18 September 2014,
15-16 September 2014,
5-6 October 2014,
19-23 October 2014,
10-11 November 2014,
8-9 December 2014,
22-26 December 2014,
18-22 December 2014,
I want this array to be sorted:27-29 June 2014,
13-14 July 2014,
3-4 August 2014,
17-21 August 2014,
14-18 September 2014,
14-18 September 2014,
15-16 September 2014,
21-23 September 2014,
5-6 October 2014,
19-23 October 2014,
10-11 November 2014,
8-9 December 2014,
18-22 December 2014,
22-26 December 2014,

Please help how to sort this array programatically in iphone

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find something else use my suggestion, this will sort your time by the second starting from 1/1/1970:

Transform your format date into UNIX time format (Unix timestamp based on seconds since standard epoch of 1/1/1970).

Mon: December, Day: 12, Year: 2014, Hr: 15, Min: 09, Sec: 41 => Unix time: 1418396981

Find transform formula here: [Unix time conversions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983441/unix-time-conversions-in-c-sharp), or search what programming language you are using a small snipet of code.

After you have your array, collection or whatever you can easy apply ordering. 
You can find Unix converter time online to understand better.